# Active Toggle switch to change pricing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I built a page that has three payment plans. There is also a Toggle switch, to change between `Monthly` and `Annually`.  I have the price set to ex. $19.99 for monthly and when I click the toggle button to switch to annually I want the price to change to $199.99.  Here is the code I have so far.  All HTML and CSS so now my JS isn't working for it.  What's wrong?

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("switch");
  if (x.innerHTML === "$19.99") {
    x.innerHTML = "$199.99";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "$19.99";
  }
}
```

```css
input.cmn-toggle-round:checked+label:after {
  margin-left: 32px;
}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  left: 47.5%;
}

.cmn-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -9999px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.cmn-toggle+label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  user-select: none;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round+label {
  padding: 2px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  border-radius: 60px;
  
}

input.cmn-toggle-round+label:before,
input.cmn-toggle-round+label:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  content: "";
}

input.cmn-toggle-round+label:before {
  right: 1px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 60px;
  transition: background 0.4s;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round+label:after {
  width: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: margin 0.4s;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round:checked+label:before {
  background-image: Linear-Gradient( to left, hsl(236, 72%, 79%), hsl(237, 63%, 64%)
  
);
}
```

```html
<div class="switch" onclick="myFunction()">
  <input id="cmn-toggle-1" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round" type="checkbox" />
  <label for="cmn-toggle-1"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you properly format your code snippet? because it looks like you have HTML, JS and CSS jumbled up in the same place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problem with your code. First you compare against the innerHTML property which isn't initially set this can not work until you have a default value.

The next is that you want to set the wrapper containers innerHTML which will remove the button.

In the solution below I introduced an paragraph with an initialValue of 199.95 and then toggle on it.

Also I replaced the incline scripting and used instead an eventListener.

```js
let inp = document.getElementById("cmn-toggle-1");
inp.addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("par");
  if(x.innerHTML === "$199.99"){
     x.innerHTML = "$19.99";
  }else{
    x.innerHTML = "$199.99";
  }
}
```

```css
input.cmn-toggle-round:checked+label:after {
  margin-left: 32px;
}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  left: 47.5%;
}

.cmn-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -9999px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.cmn-toggle+label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  user-select: none;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round+label {
  padding: 2px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  border-radius: 60px;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round+label:before,
input.cmn-toggle-round+label:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  content: "";
}

input.cmn-toggle-round+label:before {
  right: 1px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 60px;
  transition: background 0.4s;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round+label:after {
  width: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: margin 0.4s;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round:checked+label:before {
  background-image: Linear-Gradient( to left, hsl(236, 72%, 79%), hsl(237, 63%, 64%));
}
```

```html
<div class="switch">
  <input id="cmn-toggle-1" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round" type="checkbox" />
  <label for="cmn-toggle-1"></label>
  <p id="par">$199.99</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I've been playing around with it and it does work well.  Is there something I am missing if I want this to change multiple numbers at once?  ex. ( 19.99 to 199.99, 24.99 to 249.99 and 39.99 to 399.99). I've tried making a new function but it seems to cancel the old one out

Comment: Can you change your code, but toggle means switch between two values for multiple you need another logic and it is  not a toggle

Answer (score 0):

Having just read the comment about using the code to manipulate prices for several elements you need a different approach as using an ID will no longer work - ID attributes must be unique so unless you get tricky with numerically incremented indices and the like ( messy ) you can inspect the `target` attribute of any `click` event ( or other type ) and use parent/child/sibling selectors to identify and manipulate nodes of interest.

The HTML below was slightly modified by adding `dataset` attributes and ignoring any ID attributes present. The CSS was hastily fudged to facilitate the display.... but I think it shows how you might do it.

An event listener is assigned to each parent DIV (`.switch`) and the `currentTarget` property of the `event` is used to find the label which actually receives the click. Using the combination of `parentNode` and `querySelector` we can identify the nodes we need to make the logic work

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div.switch').forEach( div=>{
  div.addEventListener('click',e=>{
    if( e.target === e.target.parentNode.lastElementChild ) {
      let span=e.target.parentNode.querySelector('span');
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--currency','$')

      span.dataset.price=e.currentTarget.dataset.state == 1 ? e.currentTarget.dataset.annual : e.currentTarget.dataset.month;
      span.dataset.period=e.currentTarget.dataset.state == 1 ? 'Monthly:' : 'Annually:';
      span.dataset.currency=document.documentElement.style.getPropertyValue('--currency');

      e.currentTarget.dataset.state = 1 - Number( e.currentTarget.dataset.state );
    }
  })
})
```

```css
input.cmn-toggle-round:checked + label:after {
  margin-left: 32px;
}

.switch {
  --left:47.5%;

  position: relative;
  left: var(--left);

  margin:1rem 0 1.5rem 0;
  width:calc(80% - var(--left));
}

.cmn-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -9999px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.cmn-toggle+label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  user-select: none;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round+label {
  padding: 2px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  border-radius: 60px;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round+label:before,
input.cmn-toggle-round+label:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  content: "";
}

input.cmn-toggle-round+label:before {
  right: 1px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 60px;
  transition: background 0.4s;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round + label:after {
  width: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: margin 0.4s;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round:checked + label:before {
  background-image: Linear-Gradient( to left, hsl(236, 72%, 79%), hsl(237, 63%, 64%) );
}


span:after{
  display:inline-block;
  float:right;
  clear:none;
  margin:0;
  content:attr(data-period)' 'attr(data-currency)attr(data-price)!important;
}
```

```html
<div class='switch' data-state=0 data-month='199.99' data-annual='19.99'>
  <span></span>
  <input id='cmn-toggle-1' class='cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round' type='checkbox' />
  <label for='cmn-toggle-1'></label>
</div>

<div class='switch' data-state=0 data-month='259.99' data-annual='23.99'>
  <span></span>
  <input id='cmn-toggle-2' class='cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round' type='checkbox' />
  <label for='cmn-toggle-2'></label>
</div>

<div class='switch' data-state=0 data-month='150.00' data-annual='75.00'>
  <span></span>
  <input id='cmn-toggle-3' class='cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round' type='checkbox' />
  <label for='cmn-toggle-3'></label>
</div>

<div class='switch' data-state=0 data-month='652.50' data-annual='480.50'>
  <span></span>
  <input id='cmn-toggle-4' class='cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round' type='checkbox' />
  <label for='cmn-toggle-4'></label>
</div>

<div class='switch' data-state=0 data-month='40.00' data-annual='19.99'>
  <span></span>
  <input id='cmn-toggle-5' class='cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round' type='checkbox' />
  <label for='cmn-toggle-5'></label>
</div>

<div class='switch' data-state=0 data-month='300.00' data-annual='14.99'>
  <span></span>
  <input id='cmn-toggle-6' class='cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round' type='checkbox' />
  <label for='cmn-toggle-6'></label>
</div>
```